# How Can I Change Height in ViewCell

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to change ViewCell on listview, but the code below not work for me:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell Height="100">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Seller.Thumbnail}}" Aspect="AspectFit" />
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                <Label Text="{Binding CouponName}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="12" />
                <Label Text="{Binding EndOffer}" FontSize="11" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the height for the ViewCell should work.

Try setting your StackLayout's `VerticalOptions` and `HorizontalOptions` to `FillAndExpand`.

Comment: See [Daniel Luberda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31135950/199364), for discussion of ListView.RowHeight vs ViewCell.Height.

Answer (score 71):

- If all cells have the same size set `ListView.RowHeight` property on
  ListView itself
- If you want to set `ViewCell.Height` instead
  then set `ListView.HasUnevenRows` to `true` (but it has some performance impact)

Comment: Setting `HasUnevenRows="true"` is the real answer here

Answer (score 16):

The correct now in 2019 is put this for fix height:

```
<ListView RowHeight="100" />
```

If yout don't want fix height in all rows, use:

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="true" />
```

Answer (score 12):

Setting the `height` for the `ViewCell` will work only if `ListView.HasUnevenRows` or `TableView.HasUnevenRows` property set to `true`.

Comment: True, but see Daniel Luberda's more complete answer above, which already said this.

Answer (score 4):

Just set Grid's **RowDefinition**'s **Height** to ***Auto***, wherever your Label it's wrapped. Like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Gastos}" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell >
                <Grid Padding="5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Id}" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Descripcion}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Important: This answer is for labels that may **WordWrap** to **multiple lines** of text. If doing so, don't forget **HasUnevenRows="True"**, as seen in the code snippet above.

Answer (score -2):

Height / Weight properties are mostly read-only in Xamarin.You can't set size of ViewCell.

However , you can change your StackLayout's HeightRequest property to achieve what you want.

Comment: "generally" being the key term here.  In the case of ViewCell however it is get/set.  If you look at the intellisense that pops up on that property in Visual Studio this is confirmed.

You do have to keep in mind that the RowHeight of the ListView itself will take precedence.  So setting the .Height of a CellView can appear to to not have any affect.  It is primarily meant to be used in conjunction with  `ListVIew.HasUnevenRows=true`